# Create View with SUM values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not sure how to approach this, I want to create a view

The columns are FullName, StudentID, HoursPassed, HoursFailed and HoursPassed+HoursFailed of students majoring in Finance.

BUT my column headings need to be FullName, StudentID, HoursPassed, HoursFailed and HoursAttempted

So far I have:

```
CREATE VIEW A5T7 AS
SELECT (firstname || ' ' || lastname) AS "FullName", StudentID, HoursPassed, HoursFailed, 
SUM (HoursPassed,HoursFailed) AS "HoursAttempted",
FROM A5
WHERE Upper(Major1)='FIN'OR Upper(Major2)='FIN'
GROUP BY ???
ORDER BY HoursAttempted;
```

I am pretty sure my query is wrong, somewhere. I just don't know how to approach the Heading Name and the SUM value. Also my GROUP BY doesn't seem right.

I need the five columns but also the SUM function to add that last column

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I did, I realized i had to change my GROUP BY to Where and include OR, but it still wont let me create the table @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

`SUM()` only takes one argument.  So, you might try this:

```
CREATE VIEW A5T7 AS
    SELECT (firstname || ' ' || lastname) AS FullName,
           StudentID, HoursPassed, HoursFailed, 
           SUM(HoursPassed + HoursFailed) AS HoursAttempted
    FROM A5
    GROUP BY Upper(Major1) = 'FIN' AND Upper(Major2) = 'FIN'
    ORDER BY HoursAttempted;
```

EDIT:

The above doesn't work because the `group by` clause is really a `where` clause.  I think you mean:

```
CREATE VIEW A5T7 AS
    SELECT (firstname || ' ' || lastname) AS FullName,
           StudentID,  
           SUM(HoursPassed + HoursFailed) AS HoursAttempted
    FROM A5
    WHERE Upper(Major1) = 'FIN' AND Upper(Major2) = 'FIN'
    GROUP BY firstname, lastname, StudentId
    ORDER BY HoursAttempted;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72c65) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: The name is A5 sorry... it does look like AS

Comment: I tried what you said and it gives me an error SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: I actually changed 
    WHERE Upper(Major1) = 'FIN' OR Upper(Major2) = 'FIN'

But the GroupBy is limiting my columns... I need those five FullName, StudentID, HoursPassed, HoursFailed and HoursAttempted

Comment: @AnaMar . . . If you remove the `group by`, remove the `sum()`.

Comment: I think I can't remove the Group by because I have the sum function i need.  How do I group by to keep 5 columns